# Trying to understand why a compare does not work but a filter does (Panda)

Tags: python, pandas

```
dfclean = dfclean[dfclean['Count'] > 1]
```

I used this to clean out 'Count' values of < 1 from a data frame. The column 'Count' had vales from 0-3It worked well.

```
dfsorted = dfbottom.groupby("ST").filter(lambda dfbottom:dfbottom.shape[0] > 1)
```

I used this to filter out instances of "ST" that were < 1. I wanted only values in the dataframe that had > 1 instance. I used this after pouring through stackoverflow for a while and found the right code to understand.

```
dfbottom = dfbottom[dfbottom.groupby("ST").count() > 1]
```

What I need help understanding, if possible, is why didn't this work? In my mind this should do a similar cleaning job (Look at the column "ST", count the values, where it finds values > 1 keep the data. Instead what happened in is the Dataframe ends up with all NaN values. If I run just the dfbottom code I get a table of "True" & "False". The table is correct but I am clearly missing the proper formatting to use that data to create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `.count` aggregate DataFrame.

Solution is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, so possible filtering:

```
dfbottom = dfbottom[dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].transform('count') > 1]
```

**Sample**:

```
dfbottom = pd.DataFrame({'ST':list('abbbcec')})
print (dfbottom)
  ST
0  a
1  b
2  b
3  b
4  c
5  e
6  c

dfbottom = dfbottom[dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].transform('count') > 1]
print (dfbottom)
  ST
1  b
2  b
3  b
4  c
6  c
```

**Details**:

```
print (dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].transform('count'))
0    1
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    2
5    1
6    2
Name: ST, dtype: int64

print (dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].transform('count') > 1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: ST, dtype: bool
```

---

If want filter by aggregate values:

```
print (dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].count())
ST
a    1
b    3
c    2
e    1
Name: ST, dtype: int64

print (dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].count() > 1)
ST
a    False
b     True
c     True
e    False
Name: ST, dtype: bool

print (dfbottom[dfbottom.groupby("ST")['ST'].count() > 1])
```

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

This cannot working, because different size of boolean mask - in this sample is lenght `4` and original `DataFrame` it is `7`.

Comment: Thanks, this achieves the same result as using the filter method. I am reading https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html now to try and help me understand groupby a bit better; I still have a lot to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @Kafka - Sure, `.filter` working here too, but  in larger `DataFrame` is faster `.transform` solution, so I like it more :)